# I have issues with installing Git on Linux

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, terminal, installation

I'm totally new to Linux and I have to install Git there.
But every time I try this appears:

```
~$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this and successfully install git?

Comment: Did you run `apt update` before trying this? Some packages might be missing from repos because of updates.

Comment: you were right. thank you for your help!